# LuaLaTeX & fwlw - supress hyphenation in \NextWordBox

Tags: luatex, koma-script, hyphenation

If I use LuaLaTeX and fwlw package, word in \NextWordBox is hyphenated, it is undesirably.
(If XeLaTex - no).
Can it be fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage[includefoot=true,papersize={15em,20em}]{geometry}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\rofoot{\usebox\NextWordBox}
\refoot{\usebox\NextWordBox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\textwidth=10em%
\textheight=29ex%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

---

### XeLaTeX pdf:

[image]

---

### LuaLaTeX pdf:

[image]

Comment: Note that xelatex also does it: `tor` on the second page instead of `tortor`.

Comment: `fwlw` package documentation (one page, `texdoc fwlw`) says: "Note that ‘words’ are any unsplittable unit and may be things like: ... partial words like ‘par-’ or ‘-tial’ due to hyphenation." Switching hyphenation off at that point could be a solution?

Comment: @Cicada, yes, I see (with xelatex word are unhyphenated **always** in my texts). But may be it can be set explicitly - no hyphenation in \NextWord?

Comment: @Cicada, And `tor` on second page are normally behaviuor

Comment: I don't know. No hyphenation would have to be set *before* NextWord is created. Unrelated: in old books, only the first (or last) part of a long word was placed: e.g., `insi-` instead of `insipida` on p 151 of https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Defensio_Animadversionum_et_Notarum_P_La/pTdkAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=vehicula&pg=PA150&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @Cicada I need whole word - for liturgical texts, when one's reading or singing - whole next word helps for eye focusing :-)

Comment: Page-turning requires short nextwords (page is turned while nextword is said/sung), plus eye focusing for next page needs to land on fixed position (top left or top right) for quick pick-up, so short nextword also helps for this.