# Fwlw package and \part at scrbook KOMA-Script class error

Tags: koma-script

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\begin{document}
\part{Test}
\chapter{Chapter test}
Text
\end{document}
```

I got error: `Incompatible list can't be unboxed. \part{Test}`

With book class - no errors.

Should I play with pagestyles for part?

Comment: No errors with the `memoir` class either.

Comment: Full error in log:   
   
! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.
<argument> \@tempboxa 
                      
l.4 \part{Test}
               
Sorry, Pandora. (You sneaky devil.)
I refuse to unbox an \hbox in vertical mode or vice versa.
And I can't open any boxes in math mode.

Comment: Interestingly other people seem not to have had the same issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569858/

Comment: @Ingmar No, with `\part{}` error again in code from this link.

Answer (score 1):

I found this piece of code from `scrbook.cls`: (str:194-196)
`KOMAScriptVersion{2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script}`

```
\newcommand*{\partheadendvskip}{%
  \vskip\@tempskipa\newpage
}
```

and if I comment \newpage - error disappear.

```
\renewcommand*{\partheadendvskip}{%
  \vskip\@tempskipa%
  %\newpage
}
```

But `\newpage` still needed :-) and I can add it by hand after \part{}.
Or modify this code:

```
\renewcommand*{\scr@@endpart}[1]{%
  \vbox to\z@{\use@preamble{#1@u}\vss}%
  \@tempskipa=\glueexpr\csname scr@#1@afterskip\endcsname\relax\relax
  \ifdim\@tempskipa<\z@\@tempskipa-\@tempskipa\fi
  \partheadendvskip
  \partheademptypage
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
  \cleardoubleoddpage%   <---- ADD
  \thispagestyle{empty}% <---- ADD
}
```